# Reuse section of docstring from class

Tags: python-3.x, class, docstring

I have a docstring section (from Attributes to Methods) that is exactly the same for other classes. Is there a way to make a function or something to include that section in all other classes. I'm using a parent class and if I add something else to that class, I don't want to go over all my code to make the change. Do I have to add something to the parent class to do that?
I'm using python 3.9

```
class MaskCls(Template):
    """
    Description.....
   
    Attributes
    ----------
    array : numpy.ndarray
        Output array
    
    Methods
    -------
    mask(mask_aoi, mask_aoi_vl=None, replace_im=None, reverse=False, output=None):
    
    save(output, format_out="GTiff"):


    """
    
    def __init__(self, to_raster, from_raster, mask_rules, val_to_assign=None):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...

    def method(self):
        """a doctring for this method\n"""
        ...



class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...

    def method(self):
        ...

    def method2(self):
        ...
    
    method.__doc__ = Parent.method.__doc__
    method2.__doc__ = Parent.method.__doc__ + """some new infos"""
```

what it does is duplicating the docstring of Parent.method to Child.method.
for Child.method2 whe use a modified version of the Parent.method's docstring.

so when testing:

```
print(Parent.method.__doc__)
print(Child.method.__doc__)
print(Child.method2.__doc__)
```

it shows us:

```
a doctring for this method

a doctring for this method

a doctring for this method
some new infos
```

but unfortunatly many ide will not comprehend what whe did, they are likely to show us the docstring of Parent.method for the Child.method, not because of what we did but because they have the same name, and class heritage (note that without the manual chages Child.method.**doc** whould still be equal to None), and for the Child.method2's docstring, nothing will be shown by the ide.

you can explore some more advanced technics here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3140